# Modify global javascript variable inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying clone a json object inside a function wanting to access the object outside the function. But when function is done, the object still seems to be undefined. Seems like it's not the same variable?

```
var jsonUserObj;
$.getJSON("user.json", function(content){
    jsonUserObj = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(content));
    console.log(content);
    console.log(jsonUserObj); //looks fine!
});
console.log(jsonUserObj); //undefined
```

inside the callback function it contains all the data, but it does not remain outside of it. How to make it assessible globally?

Comment: Typo:  `jsonUserObject` !== `jsonUserObj` That's the reason for the `undefined`.  The asynchronous call however, will cause it not to have the new values when you view it immediately following the `getJSON()` call.

Answer (score 2):

$.getJSON is asynchronous so console.log at the end of your code runs before $.getJSON returns its result.

You should modify the variable inside the callback (where *it looks fine*) and then use the variable inside that function, this callback is the only place where you can guarantee your variable is set.

You could also use the synchronous version of $.ajax but that's really not recommended (and probably unnecessary).

Comment: Hm ok. I can do that, but wanted to avoid it. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

You got a typo:

```
console.log(jsonUserObject);
```

It should be

```
console.log(jsonUserObj);
```

Comment: Sorry about the type. Problem still remains though.

Comment: This is because you are using a async function @kabaros explained the behavior of your code

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `var jsonUserObj` outside a function.

Also it looks like you have a typeo, is it jsonUserObj or jsonUserObject?

Comment: Right, but where is he calling the get?  It needs to be called from somewhere, I assume this whole block is contained in another funtion

Comment: Doesn't matter though - it is still declared at a higher scope than the getJSON() call, so even if the whole thing is wrapped in a function the scope will still work for this example.

Comment: That doesn't make it global, which is what he states he wants it to be, it makes it scoped to the function.

Comment: But you're making the inference that this is all inside a function you can't see and imagine exists.

Comment: i have tried to put it in a function and actually call it, but asynch problem still there.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a question of timing? If that getJSON method is firing asynchronously then it may not have returned it's value by the time you have fired the last line. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

`$.getJSON` performs an ajax call, which is asynchronous. The code after it will continue evaluating while it waits for a response. When the response comes back, the program flow will jump back into the success/error/complete handlers of the ajax call.

tldr: Anything you do with data from an ajax call must be in the success handler of that ajax call.